# Asymptote of the prime gap

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, asymptotics, prime-gaps

A famous conjecture in number theory states that $p_{n+1}-p_n=O((\log p_n)^2)$, where $p_n$ is the $n$-th prime number. However, it is well-know that $p_n \sim n\log n$. So why is the leading conjecture not that $p_{n+1}-p_n \sim n\log n$, since $(n+1)\log(n+1)-n\log n \sim \log n$?

Comment: The primes look like randomly distributed with probability that $n$ is prime $\approx 1/log n$. The bound for the prime gap is not about the mean value of the prime gap ($\log n$) but the mean plus the variance.

Comment: $a_n \sim \alpha_n$ and $b_n \sim \beta_n$ does not necessarily imply $a_n-b_n \sim \alpha_n -\beta_n$. You have to take into account the error terms. There is a more precise asymptotics for $p_n$ which has an error term that would give you an estimate for the error of that difference which is much larger than $\log n$. Even under RH you would get $p_{n + 1}  - p_n  = \mathcal{O}(p_n^{1/2 + \varepsilon } )$.

Comment: @Gary The $\frac12+\varepsilon$ exponent is achieved by Lindelöf hypothesis, and RH strengthens this to $p_{n+1}-p_n=O(p_n^{1/2}\log p_n)$.

Comment: @TravorLZH I know, I just did not bother to calculate the right power of $\log$.

Comment: $\ln^2(p)$ might be an upper bound for the prime gap from $p$ to the next prime , but this is unknown. There is no known counterexample for this bound, but the best proven upper bound is much worse, namely $p^{0.525}$ for sufficiently large $p$.